# How to display values from two tables in uitableviewcell

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview, parse-platform

I'm beginner of Parse.com BaaS. 
I'm thinking about how to display in one `UITableViewCell` data from two tables which are connected by pointer. I've got a table named "PackageItems" which contain columns such as:- objectId, packageId, productId, price. In the second table named "SIZES", I store data with attributes like:- objectId, packageItemsId, quantity and sizeTypeId. In the third table named "SIZE_TYPES", I have a columns named:- objectId & typeName. I connect these three tables by pointers in SIZES table like below: packageItemsId -> POINTER -> target class-> PACKAGE_ITEMS sizeTypeId -> POINTER -> target class -> SIZE_TYPES

After that I create a query which return as result every Sizes connected to PackageItems by Pointer packageItemsId.

```
-(PFQuery *)queryForTable
{
    PFQuery *query = [PFQuery queryWithClassName:@"Size"];
    PFObject *packagedItem = [PFObject objectWithoutDataWithObjectId:@"SxtIpSJ64t"];
    [query whereKey:@"packageItemsId" equalTo:packagedItem];
}
```

In the `cellForRowAtIndexPath` method, I display quantity from Sizes table like below in the `UITextField` and also I try to display typeName from table SIZE_TYPES

```
-(UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath object:(PFObject *)object{
    static NSString *simpleTableIdentifier = @"PackageCell";
    UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:simpleTableIdentifier];
    if (cell==nil) {
        cell = [[UITableViewCell alloc]initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleSubtitle reuseIdentifier:simpleTableIdentifier];
        cell.selectionStyle = UITableViewCellSelectionStyleNone;
        UILabel *sizeLabel = [[UILabel alloc]init];

        sizeLabel.text = @"HERE I WOULD LIKE TO DISPLAY VALUE OF SIZE TYPE"


        sizeLabel.frame = CGRectMake(20,5,50,34);
        [cell.contentView addSubview:sizeLabel];

        UITextField *quantityField = [[UITextField alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(245, 5, 55, 34)];
        quantityField.borderStyle = UITextBorderStyleRoundedRect;
        quantityField.keyboardType = UIKeyboardTypeNumberPad;
        quantityField.textAlignment = NSTextAlignmentRight;
        quantityField.text = [object objectForKey:@"quantity"];
        [cell.contentView addSubview:quantityField];

        UILabel *quantityLabel = [[UILabel alloc]init];

        quantityLabel.textAlignment = NSTextAlignmentRight;
        quantityLabel.text = @"Quantity:";
        quantityLabel.frame = CGRectMake(170, 5, 70, 34);
        [cell.contentView addSubview:quantityLabel];


    }
    return cell;
}
```

I know that the query can return only value from one class. I also tried to create second method that returned SIZE_TYPES but it seems to me that I'm doing it wrong. I've read that the charging of the two table can be done by using the method 'include' but do not really know how to go about it. I also heard about cloud code. Perhaps I should use a relationship and a little change my database schema. Please for any sensible solution.

Answer (score 0):

In your case core data maybe your best choice, checkout this one [core data programming guide](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/cocoa/conceptual/CoreData/cdProgrammingGuide.html)

and then you can try to use  NSFetchRequest and NSPredicate to query the database, that will

give you back a NSArray as return type, then you can sort the result and display them based on

the index.